# How to import data from CSV file to MS Access in C++?

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, csv, import

I am trying to upload a csv file to local Access database.

Here is my code:

```
_bstr_t bstrConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\LocalDataWarehouse.accdb;";

HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");

hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, "admin", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

string commandline = "SELECT * INTO My_TABLE FROM C:\\datafile.csv";

ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS("ADODB.Recordset");

hr = pRS->Open(commandline.c_str(), _variant_t((IDispatch *) pConn, true), ADODB::adOpenUnspecified,  ADODB::adLockUnspecified, ADODB::adCmdText);
```

I expect the program should go fectch content in `C:\datafile.csv`, and fill it to `MY_TABLE`.

However, the output is `Could not find file 'C:\datafile.mdb'`.

That's the very thing confuse me. I specify to go for a `.csv` file, but seems the database is asking for a `.mdb` file.

May I know what am I wrong, and how can I fix this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the name of the database you are trying to import this data into?

Comment: @doctorlove The name of the database is `LocalDataWarehouse`.